# During Installation process of a software using Start-Process "msiexec.exe" ... -wait, how to fix error and continue the installation process?

Tags: powershell

For the installation of the "Self-Hosted Integration runtime software, using PowerShell command
***Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/i $path /quiet /passive" -Wait***, error comes up for "DIAHostService" not having "LocalSystem" access.
I have the code to change the login to the LocalSystem ("sc.exe config "ServiceName" obj="LocalSystem") But How can I do this during the Installation Process, how do I catch the error and do the required change and continue for the installation automatically?

Code:-

```
param([string]$path, [string]$authKey)
function Install-Gateway([string] $gwPath)
{
    # uninstall any existing gateway
    UnInstall-Gateway

    Write-Host "Start Gateway installation"
    
    Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/i $path /quiet /passive" -Wait
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 

    Write-Host "Succeed to install gateway"
}
```

Comment: Put this in a script or function in a script and use Try/Catch.

Comment: This is already in a function. but during the execution the control does not move from the command "Start-Process..." to next one to make the required change. there is no pause option.

Comment: You need to show your code.  [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: full code is available here - https://github.com/nabhishek/SelfHosted-IntegrationRuntime_AutomationScripts/blob/master/InstallGatewayOnLocalMachine.ps1

Comment: Or how I can run "Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/i $path /quiet /passive" -Wait" using "LocalSystem" Account . By default its running on NT Account. How can I achieve this using the PS command?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am in no position to replicate what you are doing, take this generic approach as an example.

```
param([string]$path, [string]$authKey)
function Install-Gateway([string] $gwPath)
{
    Write-Warning -Message 'Starting Gateway uninstallation'
    UnInstall-Gateway
   
    Try
    {
        'Starting Gateway installation'
        Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList "/i $path /quiet /passive" -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Gateway installation successful.' -Verbose

    }
    Catch 
    {
        Write-Warning -Message 'AN error occurred'
        $PSItem.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

If you need to run this with a different user, then you need to add the RunAs as part of the Start-Process error logic. Yet using RunAs means starting a new Powershell instance. It will not run in the same process.

**References**

> • [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> 1. Direct - Using the environment path or local folder
> 2. Invoke-Expression (IEX)
> 3. Invoke-Command (ICM)
> 4. Invoke-Item (II)
> 5. The Call Operator &
> 6. cmd /c - Using the old cmd shell
> 7. Start-Process (start/saps)
> 8. [Diagnostics.Process] Start()
> 9. WMI Win32_Process Create() Method
> 10. Stop-Parsing Symbol --%

***see also:***

> ['powershell start-process msiexec'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20start-process%20msiexec%27&t=h_&ia=web)
>
> [Powershell: Installing MSI files](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-21-powershell-installing-msi-files)
>
> ['PowerShell start-process msiexec' try/catch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20start-process%20msiexec%27%20try%2Fcatch&t=h_&ia=web&iai=r1-2&page=1&adx=prdsdc&sexp=%7B%22prodexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22prdsdexp%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22biaexp%22%3A%22b%22%7D)
>
> [about_Try_Catch_Finally - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally)
>
> ['PowerShell error preference'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20errorpreference%27&t=h_&ia=web)
>
> [Handling Errors the PowerShell Way | Scripting Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way)
>
> [-ErrorAction and -ErrorVariable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/erroraction-and-errorvariable)

You could also look at using PowerShell jobs for this use case.

> [start-process 'about PowerShell jobs'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=start-process%20%27about%20powershell%20jobs%27&t=h_&ia=web)